# C# Position font in middle of rectangle with the biggest fitting size

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, fonts, drawstring

I'm trying to generate a font-map using C#'s Graphics class.

The characters are supposed to be perfectly in the middle of their rectangle in order to use them afterwards. Secondly, I want to use the biggest font-size with all characters fitting into their box.

[image: Example of such a font-map]

This is my attempt at doing so. However, when I run this, the characters are not in the middle of their rectangle and it seems like they're rather attached to the upper-left corner of it, considering they're pretty jump when you go trough the different maps.

```
foreach (String FontName in DataHandler.GetFonts())
            {
                foreach (FontStyle Style in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FontStyle)))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Bitmap map = new Bitmap(585, 559);
                        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(map);

                        for (int i = 0; i < charOrder.Length; i++)
                        {
                            string character = charOrder.Substring(i, 1);
                            g.DrawString(character, new Font(FontName, 30 / new Font(FontName, 20).FontFamily.GetEmHeight(Style), Style), new SolidBrush(myColor), new RectangleF(new PointF((i % charactersPerRow) * 40, ((i - (i % charactersPerRow)) / charactersPerRow) * 80), new SizeF(40, 80)));
                        }
                        map.Save(OutputPath + "\\" + Style.ToString() + "_" + FontName + ".png");
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

How would I make the characters fit perfectly into in the middle of their rectangle?

EDIT: All characters of one font would have to use the same font-size, obviously.

Comment: May you can use g.MeasureString method which gives you the space a string needs with a certain font.

Comment: You are not measuring the string, this looks like a variable pitched font where the letter i requires much less space than W.  The amount of white space above the letter doesn't match the amount of space below either.  You'd have to manually tweak that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with...

```
        int charactersPerRow = 14;
        string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-=~!@#$%^&*()_+,./;'[]\\<>?:\"{}|";
        int rows = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)chars.Length / (decimal)charactersPerRow);

        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        foreach (String FontName in DataHandler.GetFonts())
        {
            foreach (FontStyle Style in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FontStyle)))
            {
                try
                {
                    Bitmap map = new Bitmap(585, 559);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(map))
                    {
                        // each char must fit into this size:
                        SizeF szF = new SizeF(map.Width / charactersPerRow, map.Height / rows);

                        // fallback font and size
                        int fntSize = 8;
                        Font fnt = new Font(FontName, fntSize, Style);

                        // figure out the largest font size that will fit into "szF" above:
                        bool smaller = true;
                        while (smaller)
                        {
                            Font newFnt = new Font(FontName, fntSize, Style);
                            for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
                            {
                                SizeF charSzF = g.MeasureString(chars[i].ToString(), newFnt);
                                if (charSzF.Width > szF.Width || charSzF.Height > szF.Height)
                                {
                                    smaller = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (smaller)
                            {
                                if (fnt != null)
                                {
                                    fnt.Dispose();
                                }
                                fnt = newFnt;
                                fntSize++;
                            }
                        }

                        // draw each char at the appropriate location:
                        using (SolidBrush brsh = new SolidBrush(myColor))
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
                            {
                                PointF ptF = new PointF(
                                    (float)(i % charactersPerRow) / (float)charactersPerRow * map.Width,
                                    ((float)((int)(i / charactersPerRow)) / (float)rows) * map.Height);
                                g.DrawString(chars[i].ToString(), fnt, brsh, new RectangleF(ptF, szF), sf);
                            }
                        }
                        map.Save(OutputPath + "\\" + Style.ToString() + "_" + FontName + ".png");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```